# Python: Cannot install module version that I see in pypi.org

Tags: python, websocket, pip, pypi

I'm trying to upgrade my `websockets` module, and it appears version 8.1 exists in pypi.org: https://pypi.org/project/websockets/

However, `pip install websockets==8.1` throws:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
>   websockets==8.1 (from versions: 1.0, 2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5,
>   2.6, 2.7, 3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 4.0.1, 5.0, 5.0.1, 6.0, 7.0) ERROR: No matching distribution found for websockets==8.1

I must be overlooking something. Any advice others can offer would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried this with python 3.7.4 and it worked. Make sure you are running python >= 3.6.1 (min version specced in Pypi) and latest Pip

Comment: Aha! You're right--one needs 3.6+. Yikes that's stringent. Thanks for the catch! I'll accept this as soon as SO lets me...